# can't use custom views for devise in namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, view

I've created in my app devise in scope

```
scope '/business' do
    devise_for :accounts, :controllers => { :sessions => "business/sessions" }
  end
  namespace :business do
    root to: 'user_profiles#index'
    resources :user_profiles
  end
```

Saved devise templates to business/sessions (ex business/sessions/sessions/new.erb)
and wrote business/sessions controller

```
class Business::SessionsController <
  Devise::SessionsController
layout: 'temp'
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)/
    "/business"
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    '/business'
  end
end
```

but when i enter url and is send to login, i see in logs:

```
Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (94.7ms)
```

So - not layout and not custom view.
How can i tell devise to use custom layout & views?

**Update 1**
For views - they should be placed into the directory of the corresponding model  ex: `views/accounts/sessions/`

Comment: I'm not seeing `new` method on `class Business::SessionsController`, [sessions_controller.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb)

Comment: it's in parent https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb

Comment: what do you mean a parent? you have tried my answer?

Comment: `class Business::SessionsController <
  Devise::SessionsController` parent is `Devise::SessionsController`

Comment: You want custom views devise, you should add new and create action method to your custom controller, if controller in `/business/sessions_controller.rb` you should add view in `/business/sessions/` folder. Again, have you tried my answer? if my answer not works, you can tell me error and I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
 # routes.rb

 devise_for :accounts, :except => [:sessions]

  scope '/business' do
    devise_scope :account do
      get '/login' => 'sessions#new', :as => :new_account_session
      post '/process' => 'sessions#create', :as => :account_session
      delete '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_account_session
    end
  end
```

If you want customize devise session,

> Any of the logic within that controller that you want to override you
>   can override by calling that method and inserting your own logic. For
>   the list of what's in that controller, you can view the code on their
>   Github page. If you do not wish to override their methods you can
>   either leave them out, or just call super.

example :

```
def new
 super
end
```

So, I suggestion for call super on new, create and destroy action from [this sessions_controller.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb), customize controller, looks like :

```
  # bussiness/sessions_controller.rb

   class Business::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
     layout 'temp'

     def new
      super
     end

     def create
      super
     end

     def destroy
       super
     end
   end
```

And `after_sign_in_path_for` and `def after_sign_out_path_for` you can put into applocation controller looks like :

```
   # application_controller.rb

   class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   protect_from_forgery

     def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      business_path
     end

     def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
      business_path
     end
  end
```

And view `business/sessions/new.erb`

`http://localhost:3000/business/login` for login